# Array list textures

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a problem with creating buttons from an arraylist.

Here is some sample code to show my problem:

```
    piclist = new ArrayList ();

    //texturename is name of texture in database to be downloaded, this is a loop to get all texture names, results get inserted into piclist.

    piclist.Insert (0, texturename);

    Texture2D[ ] tex;

    tex= new Texture2D[piclist.Count];

        for (var i = 0; i < piclist.Count; i++) {

        // newString is url of image downloaded from web storage. piclist is used in a loop here to get urls. 
        WWW www = new WWW (newString);
        yield return www;
        Texture2D Ttex = new Texture2D (www.texture.width, www.texture.height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
        www.LoadImageIntoTexture (Ttex);  
        tex [i] = Ttex;
    }


        voidOnGUI(){
    GUILayout.BeginArea(logArea);
    scrollPosition2 = GUILayout.BeginScrollView (scrollPosition2, false, true);
    GUILayout.BeginVertical(GUI.skin.box);


     for(int i =0; i < tex.Length; i++)
        (GUILayout.Button(tex[ i ]));

    GUILayout.EndVertical();
    GUILayout.EndScrollView();
    GUILayout.EndArea();
}
```

The problem is I get the correct number of buttons created, however they all share the texture name, so I end up with `n` number of buttons all with texture `n`.

For example if my array contained textures `[A,B,C]`, I would see the buttons being created in the following order:

A -> BB -> CCC

How could I define each button to have its own texture from the arraylist?

Comment: That code wouldn't even compile because of two problems. It's better to copy and paste the real code you are using. If you don't do this, you will get an answer that has nothing to do with your problem then you and the answerer will spend the whole day changing the code in your question and answer.

Comment: It's also good idea to add the code you used to initialize the tex variable. You may want to add the C# tag to get more people help you since this is C#.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I have added more sample code as I returned home from work. I can successfully call the name of the individual textures in my tex[ i ] array to have Debug.Log display the name of the textures, however at time of displaying the textures, the textures all load and override the textures of previously created buttons. I am using Firebase from Google to get the database and storage from, the code is messy but I can successfully download the textures through www call, which I store in tex [ ].